# How can I get this javascript to call my C# method and pass a Parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have an aspx page with a button to call a C# method. The button attributes are these:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClientClick="BuildTheYear()" />
```

When I click the button I run my javascript and the last step is to call the C# 
protected void Button1_Click(string caseNumber) method.

To do this I attempted this using `javascript`:

```
function BuildTheYear() {
   var year = document.getElementById('cYear').value;
   if (year.length != 4) {
       alert('Please enter a 4 digit year only');
       return;
   }
   var number = document.getElementById('cNumber').value;
   var checkNumberValue = (number.charAt(0));

   if (checkNumberValue === "0") {
       alert('Please do not enter any zero (0) values before the case number!');
       return;
   }

   var SearchNumber= year + "-" + number;
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "Home.aspx/Button1_Click",
       data: "{s:SearchNumber}",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType:"json"
   })
   return;
```

}

I do some data validation to make sure the end results are what I need and that all works for me and I end up with a variable called year that is in this format 2017-123456.  I want to take this variable and pass it to the C# method which looks like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(string caseNumber)
    {
        if (CheckCaseNumber(caseNumber))
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Forms/InvWithTips2?CaseNumber=" + caseNumber, true);
        }
        else

            RadAjaxManager1.ResponseScripts.Add(string.Format("window.radalert(\"That casenumber was not found. Please enter valid case number!\")"));

    }
```

The methods will then open another aspx web form passing the string build by my javascript as the query string.

I am using Visual Studio and when I run the app and click the submit button I am prompted to enter my domain credentials when I do that nothing happens. I have placed a break point on the method and I'm not getting there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the ajax call and just add server side event. The server side event will be called after the client side

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="BuildTheYear()" />
```

Also if you want to have alert errors and not trigger the server side action.

You should have it like this:

```
function BuildTheYear() {
   var year = document.getElementById('cYear').value;
   if (year.length != 4) {
       alert('Please enter a 4 digit year only');
       return false;
   }
   var number = document.getElementById('cNumber').value;
   var checkNumberValue = (number.charAt(0));

   if (checkNumberValue === "0") {
       alert('Please do not enter any zero (0) values before the case number!');
       return false;
   }


   return true;
}
```

The code `return false;` will stop the service side action.